# How to execute action at exact time once a day

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduling

I have to execute action once a day. It is to end users work time if they haven't done it themselves.

Users can end their time by clicking on button that execute ActionResult in Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
[Authorize] 
public ActionResult EndWork(...) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

How can I run action like that automatically every day at midnight? Do I have to use task scheduler or Windows Service for it? I can't set trigger on database, because records are inserted to database by EndWork().
 I have a MVC 3 website.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following :

1. Write a windows service which keeps a watch on your DB and performs the action.
2. For scheduling, please see [Quartz .Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You could schedule events using something such as [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). You can see how you can get started [here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use windows scheduled tasks - create an *.exe and set the task to run the exe every night at midnight?  Or point the scheduled task at a bat file that kicks off a script to do what you need?

Answer (score -4):

You can use a if statement. Use it with a timer so that it checks current time of the day and if it meets the condition then it executes whatever action you assign to it.

Comment: @Faisal Do not vandalize an answer simply because it is a bad/useless answer. Down vote, comment, or perhaps flag it for deletion instead.

Comment: @AndrewBarber He has been vandalizing and spamming random posts for a while now.  I've been reverting them and trying to figure out how to report him.

Comment: @Corbin Flag one of the posts he has vandalized and use the "Other" field and be very clear in the description that you are reporting one of the editors and not the poster. Mods will take care of it. Also note that it is a pattern, and not just a one-time thing.

Comment: @AndrewBarber That's the thing though...  I've flagged comments and answers before, but I've never flagged edits, and I'm not sure if I even can.  I don't see the little flag or a flag button anywhere next to any of the edit.  I'll keep looking though.

Comment: @Corbin You can't flag an edit; you would flag the question/answer Faisal has vandalized and explain in the "Other" field that you are reporting Faisal Khan for vandalization, rather than the poster. I've flagged him here already. Be patient on flags; the flag queue typically has well over a hundred posts in it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ah ok then.  I assumed you could flag edits as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoCharters A user vandalized your original answer. It was fixed, and you later edited it again. However, your original answer was not an answer at all. Your edited answer *is* an answer but, *in my opinion*, is not a good one. You cannot simply use a timer in an ASP.NET website.